# Q promise with underscore .find()

Tags: javascript, find, underscore.js, promise, q

I trying to use _.find() in the context of a Q promise.

My problem seems to be from the fact that my predicate function contains a call to an asynchronous (node-style) function.

Here is my code:

```
var IsAlreadyQueued = function() {
    return Q.ninvoke(kueSearcher, 'delayed')
        .then(function(ids) {
            return Q(_.find(ids, function(id) {
                // return true; // This works
                kue.Job.get(id, function(err, job) {
                    if (job.type === 'jobtype') {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }));
        });
};
```

So as I said in comments in the code, if i do `return true;` instead of calling `kue.Job.get()` it works.

Can you see what's wrong with my use of _.find() in a promise?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're not returning anything from your find callback.

Comment: You are right. Any idea on how to rewrite the call to `kue.Job.get` in order to get the answer in the scope of the `find` callback?

Comment: Are you sure you need `find`, or can you use `map` and later strip out any nulls? Look into the promise spread and all stuff.

Comment: I think `map` would work but `find` does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use `_.find` or any other synchronous iteration method with asynchronous callbacks - it [doesn't work with `filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22027792/1048572) either. You currently try to [`return` from an asynchronous callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572), which just won't work.

You'll first need to write an asynchronous `find` function:

```
function find(arr, predicate, i) {
    i = i >>> 0;
    if (i >= arr.length)
        return Q.resolve(null);
    return predicate(arr[i], i).then(function(m) {
        return m ? arr[i] : find(arr, predicate, i+1);
    });
}
```

then you can rewrite your own method:

```
function isAlreadyQueued() {
    return Q.ninvoke(kueSearcher, 'delayed')
    .then(function(ids) {
        return find(ids, function(id) {
            return Q.npost(kue.Job, "get", id)
            .then(function(job) { return job.type === 'jobtype'; });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somehow it looks like I made it work with my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28729693/213272. Can you have a look? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you dont need to define new functions, check out the lodash example in bluebird .call documentation, i believe same is possible in q

Comment: @Esailija: You mean that `.call("map", function(fileNames, firstCh) {return Promise.props({…}); }).call("value").all().then(_)`? Whoa, that's disconcerting. And I can assure you that `_.find` does not know how to treat promise-returning callbacks, and there's no magic that can make it do!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I made it work with this:

```
var isAlreadyQueued = function() {
    return Q.ninvoke(kueSearcher, 'delayed')
        .then(function(ids) {
            return Q(_.find(ids, function(id) {
                return Q.ninvoke(kue.Job, 'get', id)
                    .then(function(err, job) {
                        return (job.type === 'jobtype');
                    });
            })).then(function(id) {
                return !!id;
            });
        });
};
```

Can anybody verify my solution above? Thanks!

Comment: No, that doesn't work, as `_.find` does not expect (and wait for) a promise as the return value of the predicate callback. It just sees it as a truthy value, and will yield you the first `id` in the array.

Comment: My test was indeed wrong. Thanks a lot for your answer and help!